# Parsing and doing analysis on csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I want to parse a CSV file that looks something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It86N.png). It is an excel spreadsheet.

I want to read the csv file and get the data from each column as a list. So let's say I call the fieldname 'low', I want to get the data under that field name as a list so I can do analysis on it. Until now I am reading the file using the code below but I can't figure out how to get the data from each column.

```
import csv 

filename = "csv practice file.csv"

fields = [] 
rows = [] 

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:  
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile) 

    fields = csvreader.__next__()

    for row in csvreader: 
        rows.append(row)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
yourdata = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')
```

this will read your csv file into a dictionary. Then you can call your columns as a list by :

```
yourcolumn = yourdata['columnname'].values
```

Comment: are you sure you are adding the line filename = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv'). Your error seems like you didn't define the variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy if you use [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) along with a "[list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)":

```
import csv

filename = "csv practice file.csv"

with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    fields = csvreader.fieldnames
    rows = [row['Low'] for row in csvreader]

print(fields)
print(rows)
```

If you want to get the rows associated with each the fields (and store them in a dictionary keyed by the fieldnames) you could use the built-in [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to transpose the rows and columns first, and use a "[dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays)" like this:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

filename = "csv practice file.csv"

# To get all columns.
with open(filename, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    fieldnames = next(csvreader)
    rows = zip(*(row for row in csvreader))
    data = {field: list(row) for field, row in zip(fieldnames, rows)}

print('data:')
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
data:
{'Class': ['4', '5', '9', '7', '6'],
 'High': ['465', '785', '592', '254', '962'],
 'Low': ['452', '54', '25', '78', '46'],
 'Name': ['Sara', 'Joe', 'Amanda', 'Ray', 'Bob']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that we have a file with the following data:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
3,4,5
4,5,6
```

Using `csv.DictReader` we can transform the csv lines into the following structure:

```
{'col1': '1', 'col2': '2', 'col3': '3'}
{'col1': '3', 'col2': '4', 'col3': '5'}
{'col1': '4', 'col2': '5', 'col3': '6'}
```

This can then be used to iterate through these `dict`s and collect the values column wise into a the target dict `d`. `defaultdict` makes it a little bit more comfortable as we don't have to check if key `k` already exists in the dict.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:  
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for line in csvreader:
        for k, v in line.items():
            d[k].append(v)
```

We end up having a final dict `d` containing the values grouped by column like follows:

```
{'col1': ['1', '3', '4'], 'col2': ['2', '4', '5'], 'col3': ['3', '5', '6']}
```